# Как сдвинуть картинку влево?

Tags: html, css

Не могу поднять картинку, пробую такой код:

```
<span style='padding-bottom: 10px;'><img src="/images/welcome.gif"></span>
```

— но она не хочет подниматься.

Comment: Покажите всё вёрстку этого места. Вообще, это создаёт поля под картинкой, а не поднимает её.

Comment: Ладно, тогда как поднять картинку?

Comment: Что в этом вопросе такого интригующего, что он почти **1k** просмотров набрал? О-о

Comment: @IamS, то, что ему 8 месяцев - не достаточно для такого сайта?

Comment: Влево или вверх?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:

```
 <span style='margin-bottom: 10px;'><img src="/images/welcome.gif"></span>
```

2:

```
<span style='position: relative;bottom: 10px;'><img src="/images/welcome.gif"></span>
```

***P.S***: Для позиционирования лучше подойдёт тег `div` а тег `span` заставляеь всех детей наследовать его стили

Comment: 2 заработало!

Comment: Вот это бред:

    P.S: Для позиционирования лучше подойдёт тег div а тег span заставляеь всех детей наследовать его стили

Просто `div` стандартно отображается как `block`, а `span` — как `inline-block`, от чего и зависит поведение эллемента при изменении `margin` и `padding`.